# input signal out of range error for high resolution on linux

Tags: graphics, display-resolution, hardware

My computer is dual boot with a windows10 and an ubuntu. Once I undeliberately striked the case, and a noise started from it. It seemed that this noise is from cpu fan. I restarted the computer, the noise stopped. But after that every time I try to boot on a linux (even live usb) the monitor shows `input signal out of range`, unless I set `nomodeset` or boot on a basic graphic configuration.
But the strange thing is that computer can run Windows 10 with high resolution without any problem. I can't understand whether hardware or software has a problem.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? I would say you have damaged the hardware but that is just me.

Comment: @David I used Ubuntu 20.4 and even fedora, yes it seems problem is from hardware but my question is how windows run successively?

Comment: Crosspost here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628451/input-signal-out-of-range-error-for-high-resolution-on-linux

Comment: Not the place for a question about what windows does.